# How to extract hour for MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() results?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a column with time of measurments in timestamps in INT, and I need group data by interval of a hour. I already discovered MySQL function FROM_UNIXTIME(), but is there internal instrument in MySQL to extract hour from results of this function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you mean `FROM_UNIXTIME`

```
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_column), '%Y %m %d %H'))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_col_name), '%H')
```

Check out MySQL's [Date documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

**Edit:**

Use `DATE_FORMAT` instead to reliably determine the format of the hour returned. See [DATE_FORMAT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). **Note**: The format %H will return a value of the hour in the format 00, 01, ... 23.

Comment: Try moving it to the `SELECT` clause and referencing the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixCol))
FROM tbl
GROUP BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixCol))
```

`HOUR` will extract the hour after the UNIX timestamp is coverted to a date.

[See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few years after the initial question but if you're dealing with larger datasets this may take longer to execute due to calling 2 functions for every row in the query set.

I managed to shave a couple seconds off my time by using a bit of modular arithmetic

```
GROUP BY FLOOR(time_col/(60*60) MOD 24)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that DB data in variable as date and then echo it.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($db_data);
echo date("m-d-Y", $timestamp);
```